# UICollectionView Vertical ContentOffset Issues with Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tvos

I have a UICollectionView that scrolls both vertically and horizontally under tvOS. I want to control the position of each section and as such I am using the `setContentOffset` property to align. This works well, however, when scrolling horizontally, the cells return to the vertical position they were in prior to my updating of the `contentOffset`.

The setup for the `UICollectionView`:

```
lazy var singleCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: self.generateLayout())
    cv.delegate = self.singleDelegate
    cv.dataSource = self.singleDatasource
    cv.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true
    cv.register(DemandCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cvCell")
    cv.register(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")
    cv.register(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "footer")
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return cv
}()

private func generateLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.20), heightDimension: .absolute(200))
    let tileItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    tileItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: -32, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)

    var tileGroup:NSCollectionLayoutGroup!
    if showType == .bucket {
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.03), heightDimension: .absolute(H_THUMB_SIZE.height))
        tileGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: tileItem, count: 3)
    } else {
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.03), heightDimension: .absolute(H_THUMB_SIZE.height))
        tileGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [tileItem])
    }

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: tileGroup)
    if showType == .bucket {
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .none
    } else {
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
    }

    let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(50.0))
    let header = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: "header", alignment: .topLeading)
    let footerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(40.0))
    let footer = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: footerSize, elementKind: "footer", alignment: .bottomLeading)
    footer.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
    section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [header,footer]
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)

    return layout
}
```

Within the delegate I am using the following function to tell when the standard Apple scroll is done and after it animates the change to the new location:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleSection = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.first!.section
    guard visibleSection > 0 else {return}
    guard visibleSection < parentVC.topicsArray.count - 1 else {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y - 85), animated: true)
        return
    }
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y + 75), animated: true)
}
```

Again all is fine until I scroll horizontally. The `scrollViewDidEndDecelarating` isn't called on the horizinal scroll which is just as I want. However, it does get called again after the horizontal scroll moves the collectionview vertically. The big question here is why is the horizontal scroll behavior also moving the collectionview vertically back to its original alignment?